# Flutter using changeNotifier does not change the appearance of the widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a form on my page.
When I fill out the form, if it is valid a loading pop up appears and I start to perform calculations. Depending on the state of the calculations, the message on the loading popup will change.

I'm trying to do a function in my provider which will change the message depending on the state of the popup.
When I print the values ​​they are displayed correctly but my message does not change in the widget

How I call my screen :

```
return MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider<FormCalculatorNotifier>(
        create: (BuildContext context) => FormCalculatorNotifier()
    ),
    ChangeNotifierProvider<LoaderNotifier>(
        create: (BuildContext context) => LoaderNotifier()
    ),
  ],
  child: CalculatorScreen(),
);
```

In my screen, how I call the popup and calculations:

```
Expanded(
  child:  ButtonComponent.primary(
    context: context,
    text: AppTextButton.CALCUL,
    onPressed: () async {
      await _formProvider.submitForm(context);
      if(_formProvider.state == FormProviderState.isSuccess){
        // --------------------------------------
        // Here I call the popup with the message variable 
        DialogComponent.loadingPopUp(context: context, description: _loaderProvider.message);

        // --------------------------------------
        // Here I try to change the popup message because I have my calculations
        _loaderProvider.state = LoaderState.isLoadingJsons;
        await _loaderProvider.updateMessage();
      }
    },
  ),
),
```

The popUp notifier:

```
class LoaderNotifier with ChangeNotifier {

  LoaderState state = LoaderState.isReady;
  String message = "Start...";

  Future<void> updateMessage() async{
    print('update message');
    if(state == LoaderState.isLoadingJsons){
      message = "Loading files...";
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

**EDIT: I just saw that my problem is that I call the updateMessage function after calling it from the DialogComponent**

If I want to follow my logic which is to study if the form is good to display the popup then perform the calculations and according to the calculations change the message of the popup, what to do since I will call the updateMessage function afterwards?